# error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' in background subtrator code

Tags: python, syntax-error, opencv3.0, background-subtraction, silhouette

I am trying to run this code. At the start it runs properly, but gets stuck in the middle with the following error:

> (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

I have tried changing video and path name but of no use. Can anyone please explain why I keep getting this error.

Here is the code :-

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("E:\project vid\lena_jump.avi")

_, first_frame = cap.read()

first_gray = cv2.cvtColor(first_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

first_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(first_gray, (5, 5), 0)

while True:


    _, frame = cap.read()

    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gray_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_frame, (5, 5), 0)

    difference = cv2.absdiff(first_gray, gray_frame)

    _, difference = cv2.threshold(difference, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    cv2.imshow("First frame", first_frame)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    cv2.imshow("difference", difference)

    key = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the files must be in mp4 and cant read other formats

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely with the line `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("E:\project vid\lena_jump.avi")`. Python interprets the `\` (backslash) character as an escape character so that you can have tabs and newlines in strings (i.e. `\n` and `\t`). However, you want the literal `\` character for the path. Therefore, you must use a raw string - a string that does not interpret escape characters.

Replace the line with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r"E:\project vid\lena_jump.avi")`.
Alternatively, you can escape the backslash character with another backslash character, e.g. `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("E:\\project vid\\lena_jump.avi")`